# 時系列の横結合の質問について

Tags: python, pandas

2つCSVファイルがあります：area1.csv  area2.csv
時間列の項目名はないので、
時間を基準に横結合したいなら、どうやって修正したら良いでしょうか？
ご教示いただけましたら幸いですので、どうぞよろしくお願いします！
df1 = pd.read_csv(area1.csv)
df2 = pd.read_csv(area2.csv)
df3 = pd.concat([df1, df2], axis=1)
df3.to_csv(area3.csv, index=False, encoding='utf-8')

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`index_col=0, parse_dates=True`を指定することで時間列をインデックスとして読み込めますので、あとはそのまま結合すればよいです。
そして`to_csv`時はインデックスも出力するようにします。
さらに時間フォーマットを入力と合わせるためには`date_format`を指定すればよいです。

```
import pandas as pd
from io import StringIO

s1 = """,r1
2023-02-01T07:00+0900,1
2023-02-01T07:30+0900,2
2023-02-01T08:00+0900,3"""
df1 = pd.read_csv(StringIO(s1), index_col=0, parse_dates=True)

s2 = """,r5
2023-02-01T07:00+0900,11
2023-02-01T07:30+0900,22
2023-02-01T08:00+0900,33"""
df2 = pd.read_csv(StringIO(s2), index_col=0, parse_dates=True)

df3 = pd.concat([df1, df2], axis=1)
df3.to_csv('ret.csv', encoding='utf-8', date_format="%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M%z")
"""
,r1,r5
2023-02-01T07:00+0900,1,11
2023-02-01T07:30+0900,2,22
2023-02-01T08:00+0900,3,33
"""
```